# Rethinkdb update nested object

Tags: updates, rethinkdb

I have a document like below-

```js
{  
 "badgeCount": {  
  "0e2f8e0c-2a18-499d-8e64-75b5d284e31a": 0 , 
  "c0d07f5c-25ff-4829-8145-c33c0871f889": 0 
 } , 
 "createdDate": Mon Oct 10 2016 19:25:10 GMT+00:00 , 
 "deleted": false , 
 "id": "1330c8b8-38a2-46e4-b93d-f7ff84a423ed",
 "joinedUserIds": 
 [  
  "0e2f8e0c-2a18-499d-8e64-75b5d284e31a" 
 ]   
}
```

What I want to do is remove joinedUserId "0e2f8e0c-2a18-499d-8e64-75b5d284e31a" and update badgeCount by removing first property "0e2f8e0c-2a18-499d-8e64-75b5d284e31a": 0 in the same query.

I tried updating badgeCount like below-

```js
  r.db('mydb').table('discussion').filter({"id": "1330c8b8-38a2-46e4-b93d-f7ff84a423ed"})
    .update(function(s){
      return {
        badgeCount: s('badgeCount').without("0e2f8e0c-2a18-499d-8e64-75b5d284e31a")
      }
    })
```

But it does not working. Not sure what I am missing.

Thanks
Anup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rethink doesn't work like this. It doesn't rewrite object with `update`.

So, for this case you need to `replace` current object. And, btw, better to use `get` instead of `filter`, cause it's faster. There are doing the same in this situation 'cause id field is unique.

So, if you want to remove `"0e2f8e0c-2a18-499d-8e64-75b5d284e31a"` from `badgeCount`, you should use [`replace`](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/replace/):

```
r.db('mydb').table('discussion').get("1330c8b8-38a2-46e4-b93d-f7ff84a423ed").replace(function(s){
  return s.without({badgeCount : {"0e2f8e0c-2a18-499d-8e64-75b5d284e31a" : true}}).without("joinedUserIds").merge({
    joinedUserIds : s("joinedUserIds").filter(function(id){
      return id.ne("0e2f8e0c-2a18-499d-8e64-75b5d284e31a");
    })
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works great if I want to replace only badgeCount. But I want also to remove 0e2f8e0c-2a18-499d-8e64-75b5d284e31a from  joinedUserIds in the same query. How can I do this?

Comment: I got this error by running this code - "Cannot perform without on a non-object non-sequence `null`."

Comment: @AnupDasGupta are you sure you have item with id "1330c8b8-38a2-46e4-b93d-f7ff84a423ed" in rethink?

Comment: my bad :). Thats the issue. Thanks a lot.